# Nesting lists not working even with the </li>

Tags: html, navigation

This is the block of code I am having trouble with on a website. From all the looking I have done the `<li>` and `</li>` should work just fine. However when I run it on the site it causes this list to be linked to the next list as if I never closed the list tag. If I remove everything and bring the `</li>` to right behind the `</a>` it works fine, but if say I put a space or press enter it acts as if the `</li>` does not exist.

```
<li><a href = "#">contact</a>
                        <ul class = "contact">

                                <li><a href ="#">email</a></li>
                                <li><a href ="#">phone</a></li>
                                <li><a href ="#">skype</a></li>
                                <li><a href ="#">twitter</a></li>
                                <li><a href ="#">facebook</a></li>

                        </ul>
                </li>


<li> home
</li>
```

even something as simple as this the `</li>` gets ignored.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have a div as a child of a `<ul>` or `<ol>`. Also, is your outer `<li>...</li>` enclosed in either a `<ul>` or `<ol>`?

Comment: ah, but I tried to use <ul class = "contact"> and it does not follow the styling properly and still gives same problem with the </li> being ignored.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is create valid HTML. Then work on the styling.

Comment: @j08691 so I updated to the "correct" format of html however it still comes to the same problem of the </li>, which is the base problem I am having, so I will edit the above post to show another thing I tried and still got the </li> ignored.

Comment: unless the /li is right behind the words coming after the li tag it ignores the /li tag causing it and next item to become the same list item.

Comment: In the latest version of your source, which exact `</li>` is being ignored? I put it into a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/pw2Lh35w/), but I can't find where one list item looks like it's merging with the next because of a misplaced </li>.